# Change color of single anchor link on hover in React js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to change color of one specific anchor link on hover in React.

I made two functions, `handleMouseEnter` and `handleMouseLeave`:

```
handleMouseEnter () {
    this.setState({ isMouseInside: true });
}
handleMouseLeave () {
    this.setState({ isMouseInside: false });
}
```

Then I defined  `linkstyle` like this:

```
var linkStyle;
if (this.state.isMouseInside) {
    linkStyle = { color: '#6996FF', cursor: 'pointer', textDecoration: "none" };
} else {
    linkStyle = { color:"#999D9F", textDecoration: "none" };
}
```

So in my HTML code I call it:

```
<ul style={{listStyle:"none"}} color={this.state.isMouseInside ? '#999D9F' : 'white'}
    className="footer-links">
    <li>
        <a style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
           onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} href="#/category/1">
            Pants
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
           onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} href="#/category/2">
            Shirts
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
           onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} href="#/category/3">
            Dress
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
           onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} href="#/category/4">
            Shoes
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
           onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} href="#/category/5">
            Jackets
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know that all anchor links will change color when you hover on mouse because there is only one state of variable `isMouseInside`.

So my question is: is it possible to solve this on some more efficient way without defining multiple variables and setting state of each variable for each anchor link?

Comment: please make some demo  on codesandbox etc, so that other can understand in better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links has a native [hover](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_hover.asp) event that you can easily use. Just give an id or class to the specific link and write your css:

```
// HTML
<a href="" id="linkid">Link</a>

// CSS
#linkid {
  color: #999D9F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#linkid:hover {
  color: #6996FF;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

If you are using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), you can define this component:

```
const SpecialLink = styled.a`
  color: #999D9F;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    color: #6996FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none
  }
`;
```

Comment: You are right, this is easier and more efficent than using 'states'. Thank you